# Remove duplicate rows from Pandas dataframe where only some columns have the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
A   B   C
1   2   x
1   2   y
3   4   z
3   5   x
```

I want that only 1 row remains of rows that share the same values in specific columns. In the example above I mean columns *A* and *B*. In other words, if the values of columns *A* and *B* occur more than once in the dataframe, only one row should remain (which one does not matter).

FWIW: the maximum number of so called duplicate rows (that is, where column *A* and *B* are the same) is 2.

The result should looke like this:

```
A   B   C
1   2   x
3   4   z
3   5   x
```

or

```
A   B   C
1   2   y
3   4   z
3   5   x
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `subset`, for keeping only last duplicated rows add `keep='last'`:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'])
#same as
#df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'], keep='first')
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  x
2  3  4  z
3  3  5  x
```

---

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'], keep='last')
print (df2)
   A  B  C
1  1  2  y
2  3  4  z
3  3  5  x
```

Comment: @ jezrael If I want to remove duplicates  just from a column without removing rows. Let's say I have 10 rows which is corrowponds to same time instant . So I want to write to txt file but only one time instant I want to print for all 10 rows instead of showing same time for each rows.

Comment: @Poka - If dont want remove rows, only solution is replace duplicated values to `NaN` or `empty string`. Something like [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553940/2901002)