# Pandas: Delete duplicated items in a specific column

Tags: pandas

I have a panda dataframe (here represented using excel):

[image]

Now I would like to delete all dublicates (1) of a specific row (B).
How can I do it ?

For this example, the result would look like that:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for boolean mask and then set `NaN`s by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.loc[df['B'].duplicated(), 'B'] = np.nan
```

---

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df['B'].duplicated())
```

---

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].duplicated(), np.nan,df['B'])
```

Alternative if need remove duplicates rows by `B` column:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': [1,2,1,3],
    'A':[1,5,7,9]
})
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  5  2
2  7  1
3  9  3

df.loc[df['B'].duplicated(), 'B'] = np.nan
print (df)
   A    B
0  1  1.0
1  5  2.0
2  7  NaN
3  9  3.0

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B'])
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  5  2
3  9  3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know, how to do it with "df.drop_duplicates()" ?

Comment: Yes, use `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B'])`

Comment: That is really nice ! Thanks a lot ! I am actually trying to store the "dropped" column as a new column in the existing dataframe, like that: df['name'] = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B']) ... but it does not work. Do you know why ?

Comment: @totyped - Not sure if understand - drop_duplicates remove all rows and output is another DataFrame without dupes. So not possible add to new column.

Comment: But there is possible add all columns by `join` - dupes are replaced by `NaN`s  - `df = df.join(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B']), lsuffix='_')`

Comment: Or If need replace all rows by NaNs for dupes `df = df.mask(df.duplicated(subset=['B']))`

Comment: Nice ! I also tryied this which worked: df['name'] = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['B'])['B']

Comment: Yes, it is same as first solutions `df.loc[df['B'].duplicated(), 'name'] = np.nan`, so have 4 solutions for it ;)