# Remove/sum duplicate row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe, How can i make condition that if i have a duplicate row if that they are exactly the same(Mercedes exp) I keep only one (without making the sum) Or make the sum (kia case) if there is a diffrence in rent/sale value

**Df example**

```
  cars      rent  sale
  Kia       1     2
  Bmw       1     4
  Mercedes  2     1
  Ford      1     1
  Kia       4     5
  Mercedes  2     1
```

i write this code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.DataFrame({'cars':['Kia','Bmw','Mercedes','Ford','Kia','Mercedes'],
                'rent':[1,1,2,1,4,2],
                'sale':[2,4,1,1,5,1]})

df=df.groupby(['cars']).sum().reset_index()
print(df)
```

I got **this output:**

```
       cars  rent  sale
0       Bmw     1     4
1      Ford     1     1
2       Kia     5     7
3  Mercedes     4     2
```

**Expected output**:

```
        cars  rent  sale
0       Kia     5     7
1       Bmw     1     4
2  Mercedes     2     1
3      Ford     1     1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate rows from Pandas dataframe where only some columns have the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481768/remove-duplicate-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-where-only-some-columns-have-the-sam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before aggregate `sum` - this looking for duplciates together in all columns:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('cars', sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
print(df1)
       cars  rent  sale
0       Kia     5     7
1       Bmw     1     4
2  Mercedes     2     1
3      Ford     1     1
```

If need specify columns for check duplicates:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['cars','rent','sale'])
         .groupby('cars', sort=False, as_index=False)
         .sum())
```

But if need remove duplciates separately for each column use lambda function with `np.unique` and `sum`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cars':['Kia','Bmw','Mercedes','Ford','Kia','Mercedes'],
                'rent':[1,1,2,1,4,2],
                'sale':[2,4,1,1,5,5]})
print(df)
       cars  rent  sale
0       Kia     1     2
1       Bmw     1     4
2  Mercedes     2     1
3      Ford     1     1
4       Kia     4     5
5  Mercedes     2     5 <- changed 5

df2 = df.groupby('cars', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(lambda x: np.unique(x).sum())
print(df2)
       cars  rent  sale
0       Kia     5     7
1       Bmw     1     4
2  Mercedes     2     6
3      Ford     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['duplicated']=df.duplicated()  # create a column with the info of duplicating 
row or not.
df = df[~df['duplicated'].isin([True])] # delete duplicated row.
df.drop('duplicated', inplace=True, axis=1) # delete the column that we added.
df=df.groupby(['cars'], sort=False).sum().reset_index() # group the dataframe.
```

you can do like this too