# pandas dataframe groupby without losing the column which was grouped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

On the [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68079567/remove-sum-duplicate-row-with-pandas) i posted that i have a problem to remove/sum row based on certains conditions and someone helped to right a code like this.

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
                'cars':['Kia rio','Bmw','Mercedes','Ford','Kia','Mercedes Benz'],
                'rent':[1,1,2,1,4,2],
                'sale':[2,4,1,1,5,1],
                'id':[2000,1000,3000,4000,2000,3000]
                })
print(df)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['id'], sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
print(df1)
```

But when I run the groupby method it drop **car columns**. Can anyone help me on this?

**I got this output:**

```
     id  rent  sale
0  2000     5     7
1  1000     1     4
2  3000     4     2
3  4000     1     1
```

**Expected output:**

```
    cars      rent  sale  id
    Kia       5      7    2000
    Bmw       1      4    1000
    Mercedes  2      1    3000
    Ford      1      1    4000
```

Comment: Why is `Kia` 2 times in ouput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need aggregate columns for keep it in ouput (or pass to `by` parameter like `id`), so for avoid lost `cars` column is used aggregate function `last` for last values of `cars` per groups, also is specified aggregation `sum` for another 2 columns:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('id',sort=False,as_index=False).agg(cars=('cars','last'),
                                                                       rent=('rent', 'sum'),
                                                                       sale=('sale', 'sum'))
print(df1)
     id           cars  rent  sale
0  2000            Kia     5     7
1  1000            Bmw     1     4
2  3000  Mercedes Benz     4     2
3  4000           Ford     1     1
```

If possible `split` carnames by first space and aggregate by `id` and `cars`:

```
df['cars'] = df['cars'].str.split().str[0]
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['id','cars'], sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
print(df1)
     id      cars  rent  sale
0  2000       Kia     5     7
1  1000       Bmw     1     4
2  3000  Mercedes     2     1
3  4000      Ford     1     1
```

Comment: @AhmedChater - there is in data `'Mercedes','Mercedes Benz'`, so different values, so `drop_duplicates()` not removed dupes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is happening because `cars` is non-numeric and this is skipped by default on DataFrame sum. Sum has an optional parameter `numeric_onlybool` which says:

```
numeric_onlybool, default None

    Include only float, int, boolean columns. If None, will attempt to use everything, then use only numeric data. Not implemented for Series.
```

Source:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

This question also has some good info about grouping the string parts:
[Pandas groupby: How to get a union of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841149/pandas-groupby-how-to-get-a-union-of-strings)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
                'cars':['Kia rio', 'Bmw', 'Mercedes', 'Ford', 'Kia', 'Mercedes Benz'],
                'rent':[1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2],
                'sale':[2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1],
                'id': [2000, 1000, 3000, 4000, 2000, 3000]
                })
print(df)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['id', 'cars'], sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
print(df1)
```